# systemdの依存(Wants/Requires)と順序(After)を両方設定する意味は？

Tags: linux

質問の通りなのですが、これはなんの目的で設定するのでしょうか？
Afterを設定すれば、２つのUnit間に順序関係ができるのだとしたら
依存関係（×順序関係）を設定するために使われる
WantsやRequiresは不要では無いのですか？

しかし、各種デーモンのServiceUnitを確認すると
そのようなケースが散見されます。

Systemdのロジック的に、まずWantsとRequiresを見て
起動するUnit一覧を確認する、みたいな記述をどこかで見た記憶があり、
ひょっとしてAfterを設定するだけでは、起動するUnit一覧としてSystemdに認識されないのでしょうか？

Comment: Before, Afterは逐次的に実行する指定ですが、依存関係はWants, Requiresで指定しないといけないそうです。ちなみにBefore, Afterがないと、Wants, Requiresで指定されたunitは同時に平行して起動されるそうです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afterだけでは、うまくいかない例です。

・「花見準備グループは、天気が良ければ(require)、８時に花見会場で準備を始めるために出発する」
・「花見参加グループは、花見準備グループが出発してから２時間後に(after)花見会場に向けて出発する」
天気が良ければという条件が無いと、嵐の中で花見をする事になりかねません。

順序関係と依存関係の両方が満たされるようにしないと、システムは円滑に動作しません。